# Error while unwrapping an optional. firebase

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I am working from a tutorial using firebase and have pretty much got it down.

I am having a problem when creating a user with firebase. It goes through the code. but crashes with an error that says

> error found nil while unwrapping an optional value, on the code below.

The code below is what I am using. Can anyone help on this?

```
  let user = ["provider": authData?.providerID, "Blah":"Test"] as [String : Any]
                    DataService.ds.createFirebaseUser(uid: (authData?.uid)!, user: user as! Dictionary<String, String>)


                    UserDefaults.standard.set(authData?.uid, forKey: KEY_UID)


                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: SEGUE_LOGGED_IN, sender: nil)
```

and the error appears on the code below. a user is created on the data base but the app crashes, the next time it loads the app it logs in no problems.

```
 func createFirebaseUser(uid: String, user: Dictionary<String, String>) {
    self.ref.child(uid).setValue(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort this. replaced the ? for ! in authData

```
 let user = ["provider": authData!.providerID]
```